# Subset on dataset of locations

Tags: filter, subset

I have a dataset of locations. I would like to subset data for which I have at least 3 locs per year per individual. In other words, I would like to remove data when I have 1 or 2 locs per year per individual.

Thank you !

```
>   table(data0$id, group = data0$year)
             group
              1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021
  Auberta        0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  Balou          0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   18   23   58   37    8   38   45  100   19    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  Bambou         0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    3   14    4    0    1    2    0    1    0    0    3    0    5    0
  Beret          0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    3
  Blizzard       0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    2    4   10   10
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer :

```
list_id <- split(data0,data0$id)
  coln = colnames(data0)
  data1 = data.frame()
  
  for (i in 1:length(list_id)) {
  x = as.data.frame(list_id[i])
  colnames(x) = coln
  x = x[ave(1:nrow(x), x$year, FUN = length) > 2,]
  data1 = rbind(data1, x)
      }
```

Comment: If you fixed your problem, then accept your answer as a solution.

Comment: I'm able to do it in 20 hours.. don't know why